# When should I user before_filter vs helper_method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I have the following application_controller method:

```
  def current_account
    @current_account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
  end
```

Should I be calling it using a before_filter or a helper_method?  What's the difference between the two and what should I consider in terms of the trade-offs in this case?

Thanks.

**UPDATE FOR BETTER CLARITY**

I'm finding that I can user the `before_filter` instead of the `helper_method` in that I'm able to call controller defined methods from my views.  Perhaps it's something in how I arranged my code, so here is what I have:

**controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery

  include SessionsHelper

  before_filter :current_account
  helper_method :current_user

end
```

**helpers/sessions_helper.rb**

```
module SessionsHelper

  private

  def current_account
    @current_account ||= Account.find_by_subdomain(request.subdomain)
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    if current_user
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

**controllers/spaces_controller.rb**

```
class SpacesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    unless logged_in?
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end
end
```

**views/spaces/home.html.erb**

```
<%= current_account.inspect %>
```

In theory, this shouldn't work, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no relationship between using before_filter or helper_method. You should use helper method when you have a method in your controller that you would like to reuse in your views, this current_account might be a nice example for helper_method if you need to use it in your views.

Comment: I'm using a before_filter on this method currently, and am able to call it from my views.  Am I missing something?

Comment: If this method is defined inside a controller, you can't possibly be calling it in a view, unless you are accessing the **@current_account** instance variable, which would be a bad practice.

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares, not true. If he calls `helper_method :current_account` in a controller, the method will be available in the views.

Comment: @tsherif I think that's what he's saying, that `helper_method` allows me to call it from the view, but `before_filter` does not.  My point / question is.... I'm using the `before_filter` and am able to call the method directly from the view as such:  `<%= current_account.inspect %>` -- This is what's confusing me. I'm on Rails 3.2.2, maybe something new?

Comment: @Nathan, hmmm... I just did a couple of tests locally, and I can't get `before_filter` to make a method defined in the controller available to the views. Only `helper_method` works for that. And I'm also using rails 3.2.2. Are you sure you're not calling it somewhere? Where is everything defined? What directives do you call at the beginning of application_controller?

Comment: I posted my code... perhaps this will help.  Notice I'm using the `before_filter` in the application_controller.

Comment: @Nathan You defined `current_account` in `SessionsHelper` which is available to the views by default. You then made it available to all controllers with `include SessionsHelper` in `ApplicationController`.

Comment: @James Yep, that seems to be the issue.  Just shows how little I understand the framework.  I posted an answer to my own question -- hope this helps others.  Thanks for you input.

Answer (score 3):

They are two very different things. A `before_filter` is something that you want to be called *once* before an action starts. A helper method on the other hand gets repeated often, typically in a view.

That method you have there is just fine to stay where it is.

Comment: As for each being very different, are you saying the `helper_method` does not call the method into memory for each action?  In other words, it's only used as a conduit between the view and the method, and is called as needed from the view?

Comment: No, the programmer calls `helper_method`s from the view (or other places) when they are needed. Rails automatically calls `before_filter`s before controller actions.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.  I'm new to Rails, and didn't know that methods defined in the helpers directory are automatically helper_methods.  Now I'm wondering how this effects memory/performance.  But at least I have the mystery solved.  Thanks everyone for your help!